# jsf facelets cannot find property in tomcat 7 but works in glassfish 3.1

Tags: jsf, glassfish, tomcat7

I am trying to figure out which jar I need to download for tomcat 7. I am making a call and passing an argument to a method such "availableEmployees(DepartmentName)" in my faces web page. This does not work in tomcat 7 but works in glassfish 3.1. I have added the javax.faces.2.1.20.jar "Mojarra" to my web app for jsf dependency. I have also javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.1.2.1 in my tomcat library folder.

Did anyone run into such problem ? Do I need to add more than the above jars for jsf support ? Thanks. Not using maven since it is somebody else' project.

Comment: Looks like an EL library problem in your tomcat installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using netbeans and I linked to an eclipse project. I added my own primefaces library. When I looked at the build output from netbeans, I have noticed that there were two copies of primefaces library. One with 3.4.2 and another with 3.3.1.

Removed one of them and everything worked.